# Tracking installation of apps from outside android market

Tags: android, google-play, tracking

I was wondering how could one go about tracking installations of app from a source which isn't the android app market?

is it possible to do so using google analytics SDK?

I have looked for answers far and wide, and have found nothing, so any help on this matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's possible. Use the [Android SDK for Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/android.html)  and watch the presentation  [Optimize Android Apps with Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/optimizing-android-apps-with-google-analytics.html).

Comment: I looked all around that place, saw that video and saw nothing other than tracking using campaigns which redirect to the market, am I missing something?